# async.waterfall jumping to end before functions complete

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js

Hope you guys are well?
I am diving into Node.js and having to relearn a lot of the ways in which I used to code - and having to retrain myself to asynchronous ways...  I am writing a server-side script (like a java POJO), that will run either from the command line or triggered from an event.

I wanted to have the output(return) of one function to be the input of the next so I decided to use async.waterfall - as I read this will execute the functions in order, using the output from one for the input of the other...

The idea of the script is to walk through a given folder structure, create an array of sub-folders and then pass that array to the next.  Then do the same for each path in that array.  I wanted to use underscore.js and the "_.each()" function as it seemed a good way to iterate through the array in sequence.  But this is where I get stuck as it seems to fall through all the functions to the end, before the work is complete.  So my logic is a little off somewhere..

I use a 'walk' function to go into the folder and return all sub-folders..  The idea is that the script will run and then 'process.exit()' at the end of the waterfall.

The code is:

```
    async.waterfall([
      function(callback){ /* Get List of Artists from MusicFolder */
        console.log('first->IN');
        walk(musicFolder, function(err, foldersFound) {
          if (err) { return err;}
          _.each(foldersFound, function(folderPath){
            console.log('Folder: ' + folderPath);
          });
          console.log('first->OUT');
          callback(null, foldersFound);
        });
      },
      function(artistsFound, callback){ /* Get List of Albums from Artist Folders */
        var eachLoop=null;
        console.log('second->IN');
        _.each(artistsFound, function(artistPath){
          console.log('second->eachPath:Start:'+artistPath);
          walk(artistPath, function(err, albumsFound) {
            console.log('second->Walk:Found');
            console.log(albumsFound);
            if (err) { console.log(err);}
            _.each(albumsFound, function(albumPath){
              eachLoop++;
              console.log('second->Walk:each:'+eachLoop);
            });
            console.log('second->Walk:End');
          });
          console.log('second->eachPath:End:'+artistPath);
        });
        console.log('second->OUT');
        callback(null, albumsFound);
      },
      function(paths, callback){
        console.log('third->IN');
        console.log('third->OUT');
        callback(null, paths);
      }
    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log('last->IN');
        console.log(result);
        console.log('last->OUT');
    //    process.exit();
    });
```

I have commented out the 'process.exit()' in the example.

IF I uncomment the 'process.exit()' I get the following output:

```
first->IN
Folder: /music/Adele
Folder: /music/Alex Clare
first->OUT
second->IN
second->eachPath:Start:/music/Adele
second->eachPath:End:/music/Adele
second->eachPath:Start:/music/Alex Clare
second->eachPath:End:/music/Alex Clare
second->OUT
third->IN
third->OUT
last->IN
null
last->OUT
```

What I can see is it does not enter the 'walk' function in the second waterfall function, but skips the 'walk' altogether even though the 'walk' is inside the _.each() iteration.

IF I comment out the 'process.exit()' command in the last function I get the following:

```
first->IN
Folder: /music/Adele
Folder: /music/Alex Clare
first->OUT
second->IN
second->eachPath:Start:/music/Adele
second->eachPath:End:/music/Adele
second->eachPath:Start:/music/Alex Clare
second->eachPath:End:/music/Alex Clare
second->OUT
third->IN
third->OUT
last->IN
null
last->OUT
second->Walk:Found
[ '/music/Alex Clare/The Lateness of the Hour' ]
second->Walk:each:1
second->Walk:End
second->Walk:Found
[ '/music/Adele/19',
  '/music/Adele/21',
  '/music/Adele/Live At The Royal Albert Hall' ]
second->Walk:each:2
second->Walk:each:3
second->Walk:each:4
second->Walk:End
```

I'll admit this is frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been rewriting this over and over for the past week in various 'async' forms and they all jump out of the functions too early - so everything is out of order.

Thanks for your help or thoughts in advance :)

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `walk` function is asynchronous. And you want to fire parallel asynchronous jobs, combine the result and move down the waterfall. So what you can do is to combine `async.waterfall` with `async.parallel`. Your second function may look like this:

```
function(artistsFound, callback) {
    // some code
    var jobs = [];
    artistsFound.forEach(function(artistPath) {
        jobs.push(function(clb) {
            walk(artistPath, function(err, albumsFound) {
                // some code
                clb(err, albumsFound);
            });
        });
    });
    // some code
    async.parallel(jobs, callback);
}
```

*Side note*: you don't have to use underscore.js to simply loop over an array. Modern JavaScript has a builtin `.forEach` function.

Comment: The 'Walk' function isn't asynchronous - and only returns once it has walked all folders and added them to an array which is passed once finished. - I wanted to paste it here but not allowed as I can't reply with an 'answer'.  So not sure if your async.parallel option would work - actually tried it and it does the same as mine in fairness... :) Appreciate there is a javascript .forEach, but I'm also teaching myself underscorejs, so thought it would be good to get in the habit of using it.

Comment: @Pandafinity If `walk` function is synchronous then I don't believe that the code does what you say it does. :) Anyway I'm out of ideas, so I hope someone else will solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the thought and suggestion :)    ...it's a standard 'walk' and just returns an array of strings once finished..so you just get ['subfolder path 1', 'sub folder path 2',...] type array returned.  Hope its sunny where you are..